# Tried accessing nonexisting field (analytics_app_events_exports) on node type (AnalyticsAppEventsExport)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-analytics

I am using facebook analytics for apps and using export api to get my data and i am making a following get request to get all my exports

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/[FBID]/analytics_app_events_exports?access_token={my app access token}
```

But i am getting the following error

Tried accessing nonexisting field (analytics_app_events_exports) on node type (AnalyticsAppEventsExport)

Can anyone explain ?

Comment: You need to use the id of your app. According to the error message, it seems like you used a different id instead.

Comment: yes it worked i was entering the export FBID

Answer (score 1):

You passed wrong ID, please use your App FBID:

```
HTTP GET to
https://graph.facebook.com/[GraphAPI version]/[Application FBID]/analytics_app_events_exports?access_token={app access token}
```

More info here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/export